# align text next to image using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstraps grid system to try and align the text next to the image. For some reason, it's not working for me. This what it looks like and I just want the text next to the image on the right side.

[image]

Here is my html:

```
   <div class="container">
   <h1 class="text-center">Executive Directors</h1>
   <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/majapic.jpg" width="250px">
            <h3 class="text-center">Maja Miletich</h3>
                <p><strong>Maja Miletich </strong>is the CEO of Zip Zap Zop Kids, LLC. Maja has worked with children on many levels. Having a brother with Autism has given Maja an understanding of how powerful communication is for ALL children. Maja has worked for years as a teacher where she practices emergent curriculum. Maja has studied theater and improv at A.C.T. in San Francisco as well as graduated from The Second City Training Center in Hollywood where she studied improv and sketch comedy. Maja has her Bachelors Degree in Early Childhood Education. Maja's focus is on inclusive classrooms where curriculum is designed to allow children and young adults to feel comfortable expressing themselves in whichever way they feel most comfortable. Maja believes when we can share with one another what has been taught then, and only then, are we actually learning.</p>
        </div>
   </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/majapic.jpg" width="250px">
            <h3 class="text-center">Maja Miletich</h3>
                <p><strong>Maja Miletich </strong>is the CEO of Zip Zap Zop Kids, LLC. Maja has worked with children on many levels. Having a brother with Autism has given Maja an understanding of how powerful communication is for ALL children. Maja has worked for years as a teacher where she practices emergent curriculum. Maja has studied theater and improv at A.C.T. in San Francisco as well as graduated from The Second City Training Center in Hollywood where she studied improv and sketch comedy. Maja has her Bachelors Degree in Early Childhood Education. Maja's focus is on inclusive classrooms where curriculum is designed to allow children and young adults to feel comfortable expressing themselves in whichever way they feel most comfortable. Maja believes when we can share with one another what has been taught then, and only then, are we actually learning.</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to declare the `div` for the text in the same `.row` as the image

Comment: I thought I did declare my image and text in the same row. I have 2 rows in my code above which has an image and text in each one.

Comment: `<h3>` is block by default

Comment: even if I take it out the text still doesn't move to the same row as the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code with this

```html
   <div class="container">
   <h1 class="text-center">Executive Directors</h1>
   <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/majapic.jpg" width="250px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <h3 class="text-center">Maja Miletich</h3>
                <p><strong>Maja Miletich </strong>is the CEO of Zip Zap Zop Kids, LLC. Maja has worked with children on many levels. Having a brother with Autism has given Maja an understanding of how powerful communication is for ALL children. Maja has worked for years as a teacher where she practices emergent curriculum. Maja has studied theater and improv at A.C.T. in San Francisco as well as graduated from The Second City Training Center in Hollywood where she studied improv and sketch comedy. Maja has her Bachelors Degree in Early Childhood Education. Maja's focus is on inclusive classrooms where curriculum is designed to allow children and young adults to feel comfortable expressing themselves in whichever way they feel most comfortable. Maja believes when we can share with one another what has been taught then, and only then, are we actually learning.</p>

        </div>
   </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/majapic.jpg" width="250px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3 class="text-center">Maja Miletich</h3>
                <p><strong>Maja Miletich </strong>is the CEO of Zip Zap Zop Kids, LLC. Maja has worked with children on many levels. Having a brother with Autism has given Maja an understanding of how powerful communication is for ALL children. Maja has worked for years as a teacher where she practices emergent curriculum. Maja has studied theater and improv at A.C.T. in San Francisco as well as graduated from The Second City Training Center in Hollywood where she studied improv and sketch comedy. Maja has her Bachelors Degree in Early Childhood Education. Maja's focus is on inclusive classrooms where curriculum is designed to allow children and young adults to feel comfortable expressing themselves in whichever way they feel most comfortable. Maja believes when we can share with one another what has been taught then, and only then, are we actually learning.</p>
        </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

in each row you need do add two cols, one for the picture and one for the description, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <img class="" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/majapic.jpg" width="250px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <p> desccription here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

the description now appear next to the image.

in the bootstrap's page there is a grid's tutorial, learn it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Answer (score 5):

In Bootstrap's grid system, to get two elements side-by-side you would need to nest two `.col` divs within a single `.row`, like below:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Executive Directors</h1>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/majapic.jpg" width="250px">
            <h3 class="text-center">Maja Miletich</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p><strong>Maja Miletich </strong>is the CEO of Zip Zap Zop Kids, LLC. Maja has worked with children on many levels. Having a brother with Autism has given Maja an understanding of how powerful communication is for ALL children. Maja has worked for years as a teacher where she practices emergent curriculum. Maja has studied theater and improv at A.C.T. in San Francisco as well as graduated from The Second City Training Center in Hollywood where she studied improv and sketch comedy. Maja has her Bachelors Degree in Early Childhood Education. Maja's focus is on inclusive classrooms where curriculum is designed to allow children and young adults to feel comfortable expressing themselves in whichever way they feel most comfortable. Maja believes when we can share with one another what has been taught then, and only then, are we actually learning.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To learn more about bootstrap's grid system go [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).