# Make Name next to image in card , center a card

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two questions please:

1. How to put the name right next to the image. As you can see the word is at the top of the card not the center of the image
2. Also the card isn't centred as it should be.

[image: That's what I see]

> html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
      {% for post in posts %}
      <div class="card m-2" style="width: 50rem;">
         <div class="card-title d-flex flex-row  mb-0">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img m-2" src="{{ post.user.profile.picture.url }}" />
            <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark " href="{% url 'profile' post.user.profile.pk %}">
               <h6>{{post.user.username}}</h6>
            </a>
         </div>
         <img class="card-img-body" src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
         <div class="card-body d-flex flex-row m-0 p-0 pt-1"> 
            <a class="card-title text-decoration-none text-dark" href="{% url 'profile' post.user.profile.pk %}">
               <h6 class="m-1">{{post.user.username}} </h6>
            </a>
         <p class="card-text m-0.9">{{ post.caption}}</p>

         </div>
         <div class="m-0 p-0 pt-1">
            <h6 class="m-1">Comments:</h6>
         </div>
         {% for comment in post.comments.all  %}
         <div class="card-body d-flex flex-row m-0 p-0 pt-1">
         <a class="card-title text-decoration-none text-dark m-0" href="{% url 'profile' comment.user.profile.pk %}">
         <h6 class="m-1">{{comment.user.username}} </h6>
         </a>  
         <p class="card-text m-0.9">{{ comment.text}}</p>
         </div>
      {% endfor %}

            <div class="float-right">
            <a href="{% url 'add-comment' post.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary right m-1 ">Add Comment</a>
            </div>

      </div>

      {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373977/align-text-next-to-image-using-bootstrap), to get two Bootstrap elements side-by-side you would need to nest two `.col` divs within a single `.row`.

While you have them nested in a single row `<div class="row">`, you also have them in a single column `<div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">`. You should create another `<div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">` column like below ([source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      Column for Name
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      Column for Image
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For your second question, you can `margin:auto !important` with CSS the `div` containing the card.